# Exit from the `nohup` called from shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script from where I want to start the jmeter-server on a machine and here below is my code,

```
#!/bin/sh

#Shell script for starting the jmeter server in agent machine

startServer() {
    checkProcess=$(lsof -t -i :1099)
if [ -z "$checkProcess" ] ; then
    JmeterDirectory='/home/performance/PerfTool/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin'
    cd ${JmeterDirectory} || exit
       if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
          pwd=$(pwd)
          echo "Directory changed to $pwd"
            startJmeterServer=$(nohup ./jmeter-server &) || exit
              if [ "$startJmeterServer" -eq 0 ] ; then
                echo "service started successfully"
              else 
                echo "failed to start the service"
              fi
            
       else
          echo "Went wrong"
            fi
else
        totalNumberofService=$(lsof -t -i :1099 | wc -l)
        if [ "$totalNumberofService" -gt 1 ] ; then
            echo "There are multiple JMeter-Server process are running"
        else 
            procssKiller=$(kill -9 "$checkProcess")
            ${procssKiller}
                if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
                    echo "Process has been killed with processId $checkProcess"
                else
                    echo "Failed to kill the process with processId $checkProcess"
                fi
        fi
fi

}

startServer
```

this working fine, but after starting the jmeter server the terminal is not exiting unless I press CTRL+Z. what I have missed here

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why not write a systemd service? Is there a reason you are going with reinventing the wheel with writing service management? `startJmeterServer=$(nohup ./jmeter-server &)` What do you want the line to do? Why are you grabbing stdout of a process that is going to be run in the background? Why are you using `nohup` at all? Are you receiving hup signals?

Comment: I want to run the Jmeter-server in background, even the opened session from putty get killed, that's why I have used `nohup ./jmeter-server &`

Comment: The `if` in `cd ${JmeterDirectory} || exit; if [ $? -eq 0 ]` is redundant.  If `cd` fails, the script exits.  If cd succeeds, then the script does not exit and `$?` after the `||` is `0`, so there's no point in checking.

Comment: *Always* write error messages to stderr. `echo "Went wrong" >&2`

Comment: Thank you so much William, yeah there are redundancy which I am going to enhance. Yeah sure will implement the same

Comment: `var=$(cmd &)` tells the shell to assign *all* the stdout output of `cmd` to `var`. So the shell has to wait until `cmd` cannot produce any more output before continuing. To continue sooner, close stdout (you might as well close stderr too): `var=$(cmd 1>&- 2>&- &)`. Note that your `|| exit` will never be invoked

Comment: oh, and `[ "$startJmeterServer" -eq 0 ]` probably doesn't behave the way you think, given that `var=$(cmd &)` doesn't assign the exit status of running `cmd`, so you might as well just call `nohup` directly if you don't want to use a standard service manager / daemonizer